# Javascript how do I get values from generated cells in HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table (check screenshot) where I can generate rows and the second column will contain a number from a text field. I want to be able to grab that number from a generated cell and perform calculations with it. I am not entirely sure how to target the cell that gets generated given I can generate X amount of rows. The principle for this table is to generate numbers from a text field and then press a button and the third column will display a sum of all previous second column values. The execution will start after a button is pressed which I will add later

[image: Screenshot]

```js
var counter = 1;
var pNum = 0;
var i;

//Target elements
let btnAdd = document.getElementById('btn');
let testBtn = document.getElementById('test');
let table = document.getElementById('table1');
let bTimeInput = document.querySelector('#bTime')
let bValue = document.querySelector('bCell');

//check for empty value
function checkForEmpty(input) {
    if(input.value == null || input.value == undefined || input.value.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(checkForEmpty(bTimeInput)) {
        alert('Enter a number')
    } else {
        counter++;
        pNum++;
        let bTime = bTimeInput.value;
        let wTime = 'dummyValue';
        let taTime = 0;
        let template = `
        <tr>
        <td>${pNum}</td>
        <td>${bTime}</td>
        <td>${wTime}</td>
        
        </tr>`;
        table.innerHTML += template;
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>FCFS CPU Scheduling Algorithm</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="data">
                <input type="number" id="bTime" placeholder="enter burst time">
                <button id="btn">Add process</button>
            </div>

            <table id="table1">
                <tr>
                    <th>P#</th>
                    <th id="bCell">burst time</th>
                    <th>wait time</th>
                    <th>t/a time</th>
                </tr>
            </table>

           

        </div>

        <script src="algorithm.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post code examples etc.

Comment: @Bibberty code added, thank you

Comment: Your code is violating a key principle of programming: the separation of content and presentation. Adding a row should add the values to a suitable data structure (like an array of objects), then your HTML should update to represent the changed app state. You should never have to rely on the DOM of your own app to grab values you had access to earlier (but only used to create that DOM in the first place).

Comment: Good point Chris

Comment: i created a literal array that has all the records of the html elements.. scroll a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I added some class and row pointers to help out. see what you think.

```js
var counter = 0;
var pNum = 0;
var i;

//Target elements
let btnAdd = document.getElementById('btn');
let testBtn = document.getElementById('test');
let table = document.getElementById('table1');
let bTimeInput = document.querySelector('#bTime')
let bValue = document.querySelector('bCell');

//check for empty value
function checkForEmpty(input) {
    if(input.value == null || input.value == undefined || input.value.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

const getTotalTime = (bTime, counter) => {
  if (counter === 1) return bTime; 
  const { innerText: pTime } = document.querySelector(`tr.row${counter-1} td.col4`);
  return parseInt(bTime, 10) + parseInt(pTime, 10);
};

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(checkForEmpty(bTimeInput)) {
        alert('Enter a number')
    } else {
        counter++;
        pNum++;
        let bTime = bTimeInput.value;
        let wTime = 'dummyValue';
        let taTime = 0;
        let template = `
        <tr class="row${counter}">
        <td class="col1">${pNum}</td>
        <td class="col2">${bTime}</td>
        <td class="col3">${wTime}</td>
        <td class="col4">${getTotalTime(bTime, counter)}</td>
        </tr>`;
        table.innerHTML += template;
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>FCFS CPU Scheduling Algorithm</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="data">
                <input type="number" id="bTime" placeholder="enter burst time">
                <button id="btn">Add process</button>
            </div>

            <table id="table1">
                <tr>
                    <th>P#</th>
                    <th id="bCell">burst time</th>
                    <th>wait time</th>
                    <th>t/a time</th>
                </tr>
            </table>

           

        </div>

        <script src="algorithm.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a version that takes on board with Chris G mentions about seperation.

```js
var counter = 0;
var pNum = 0;
var i;

const data = {
  points: []
};

const headerTemplate = () => `
                <tr>
                    <th>P#</th>
                    <th id="bCell">burst time</th>
                    <th>wait time</th>
                    <th>t/a time</th>
                </tr>
`;

const rowTemplate = ({id, bTime, wTime, tTime}) => `
                <tr>
                    <td>${id}</td>
                    <td>${bTime}</td>
                    <td>${wTime}</td>
                    <td>${tTime}</td>
                </tr>
`;

//Target elements
let btnAdd = document.getElementById('btn');
let testBtn = document.getElementById('test');
let table = document.getElementById('table1');
let bTimeInput = document.querySelector('#bTime')
let bValue = document.querySelector('bCell');

//check for empty value
function checkForEmpty(input) {
    if(input.value == null || input.value == undefined || input.value.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

const getTotalTime = (bTime) => {
  if (data.points.length === 0) return bTime;
  return bTime + data.points[data.points.length-1].tTime;
};

const drawTable = () => data.points.map(point => rowTemplate(point)).join('');

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(checkForEmpty(bTimeInput)) {
        alert('Enter a number')
    } else {
      counter ++;
      const bTime = parseInt(bTimeInput.value);
      const newDataPoint = {
        id: counter,
        bTime,
        wTime: 'dummyValue',
        tTime: getTotalTime(bTime)
      };
      data.points.push(newDataPoint);  
      table.innerHTML = headerTemplate() + drawTable(data);
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>FCFS CPU Scheduling Algorithm</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="data">
                <input type="number" id="bTime" placeholder="enter burst time">
                <button id="btn">Add process</button>
            </div>

            <table id="table1">

            </table>

           

        </div>

        <script src="algorithm.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer to your problem cannot be given without code snippets but here is an approach which I thought of:

You can use the

```js
 const cells=document.querySelectorAll('td')
```

to get a node list of all the elements and then target specific cells by indexing this list. Then you can extract value from those node elements by

```js
 cells[index].innerText
```

or

```js
 cells[index].innerHTML
```

and perform operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var counter = 1;
var pNum = 0;
var i;

//Target elements
let btnAdd = document.getElementById('btn');
let testBtn = document.getElementById('test');
let table = document.getElementById('table1');
let bTimeInput = document.querySelector('#bTime')
let bValue = document.querySelector('bCell');

//check for empty value
function checkForEmpty(input) {
    if(input.value == null || input.value == undefined || input.value.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
var x0=[]//array for saving
btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(checkForEmpty(bTimeInput)) {
        alert('Enter a number')
    } else {
        counter++;
        pNum++;
        let bTime = bTimeInput.value;
        let wTime = 'dummyValue';
        let taTime = 0;
        
        //extremely long but successful traceable tags begin
        var x1=document.createElement('tr')
        table.appendChild(x1)//parent element in proper place
        //now to create children
        var x2=document.createElement('td')
        var x3=document.createElement('td')
        var x4=document.createElement('td')
        //now to apply data to children
        x2.innerText=pNum
        x3.innerText=bTime
        x4.innerText=wTime
        //now to deploy the children
        x1.appendChild(x2)
        x1.appendChild(x3)
        x1.appendChild(x4)
        //extremely long but successful traceable tags end
        //now to place in array
        x0.push({x1:x1,x2:x2,x3:x3,x4:x4})
        console.log(x0[x0.length-1])
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>FCFS CPU Scheduling Algorithm</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="data">
                <input type="number" id="bTime" placeholder="enter burst time">
                <button id="btn">Add process</button>
            </div>

            <table id="table1">
                <tr>
                    <th>P#</th>
                    <th id="bCell">burst time</th>
                    <th>wait time</th>
                    <th>t/a time</th>
                </tr>
            </table>

           

        </div>

        <script src="algorithm.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```